# My VAT calculation is wrong

Tags: javascript, decimal, calculator, parseint

I'm trying to do a function for making a small calcul with vat.

So I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calcdebours()
    {
        var taux         = document.getElementById('debours_taux_tva').value;
        var ht_no_tva     = document.getElementById('debours_montant_ht_no_tva').value;
        var ht_tva        = document.getElementById('debours_montant_ht_tva').value;
        var tva= Math.round((((ht_tva)*(taux))/100)*100)/100;
        ;
        if(taux=='')
        {
            taux=0;
        }
        if(ht_no_tva=='')
        {
            ht_no_tva=0;
        }
        if(ht_tva=='')
        {
            ht_tva=0;
        }
        document.getElementById('debours_montant_tva').value = tva  ;
        document.getElementById('debours_montant_ttc').value = (tva) + parseInt(ht_tva)+ parseInt(ht_no_tva)


    }

    </script>
```

And below the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6zzRZ/

But for all it make the wrong calculation, I think it does not count the cent.

I've tried using just var 1 + var 2 but it just used to concatenate the number sor I use the parseInt function.

It has worked but the result is wrong for any kind of amount.

The trouble is that I tried parseDecimal but it say that this function does not exist.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: and perhaps  `var tva=(parseFloat(ht_tva)*parseFloat(taux)).toFixed(2)`

Comment: Thank you so much to you, it works very fine. I just started javascript today but I did knew this function exist.

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski: Also, for future reference, it's a lot easier if you separate out your HTML and JavaScript in your fiddles. It's easier for people to read that way.

Comment: isn't (((ht_tva)*(taux))/100)*100 == (ht_tva)*(taux) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `parseFloat`. Or use the unitary `+` like this: `var ht_no_tva    = +document.getElementById('debours_montant_ht_no_tva').value;` This gives JavaScript the hint that it should treat the value as a number.

Comment: Dear sir, Thank you so much for the complete answer. Receive my utmost Respect.

Answer (score 1):

Use parseFloat() instead of parseDouble:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: http://w3fools.com/  try [MDN parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead